# Problema al exportar un módulo utilizando la librería winstom en javascript

Tags: javascript, modulos, module.exports, libreria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo tengo todo como ven allí, pero, si me funciona cuando tengo la función para crear el logger en el documento principal que no está en la carpeta "logger", es decir, todo junto en un mismo archivo si me funciona, el error está en la exportación del logger, pero no sé qué hice mal, ya instalé por medio de la terminal la librería winston, tengo una versión de node actualizada, npm, todo... ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Podes poner el código como texto en vez de imágenes? piensa que para probar tu código tenemos que ponernos a leer las imágenes en 240p e ir copiando y es bastante tedioso. Copia y pega el codigo que muestras en las imagenes para que los demas podamos copiarlo y pegarlo tambien. Saludos.

Comment: Ya encontré el error, fue al momento de poner el directorio donde se encuentra el módulo, no está claro, es de la forma: const logger = require ('./logger/app');

Comment: disculpen compas, soy ligeramente nuevo en esto

Comment: Para la próxima no pongas imágenes de tu código para eso copia, pega y ponle formato de código que para eso está.